# Работа с видео в php

Tags: php, html5, видео, ffmpeg

Нужно организовать на сайте загрузку видео, для последующего просмотра, с выбором качества 360p 720p 1080p.
Возможно ли это сделать на php, не прибегая к изменениям настройки сервера?
И как определять 360р или 720p и т.д.

Сейчас я делаю так, загружаю видео, конвертирую в mp4, сохраняю, вывожу на сайт в html5 player.

Но нет выбора качества...
А еще есть такой не большой вопрос, как у vk.com происходит обработка видео после, что после ее окончания сервис оповещает пользователя, что видео добавлено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не работал с видео-библиотками в PHP, но могу сказать, что вам точно нужно сделать:

Для начала вам необходимо создать PHP-файл, не имеющий (или имеющий очень большое) ограничение на работу по времени, а так же, который не прекращает свою работу, если пользователь оборвал соединение. Это можно реализовать рядом функций ini_set()t. В этот файл подключить библиотеки работы с видео-файлами. Скрипт должен будет сначала проверить, не побит ли файл. Далее конвертировать полученное видео в mp4, а после сделать несколько версий с разным качеством (140p,240p,360p,480p,720p,1080p,...) Если видеофайл большой (несколько гигабайт) это может занять вплоть до нескольких часов.
Не знаю, зачем вам понадобилось создать такой сервис, ведь уже есть такие сервисы как YouTube, RuTube, VK, которые имеют все эти функции, зачем изобретать велосипед, который и так уже много раз изобретен.

К вопросу о том, как VK уведомляет пользователя о окончании обработки. Если вас интересует сам процесс уведомления, то ВК каждые 30 секунд отправляет Ajax - запросы на определенный скрипт, который возвращает JSON - массив с новыми уведомлениями, если они есть. Так же получаются и сообщения, добавления в друзья, и прочие уведомления. Возможно, я неправильно понял ваш вопрос. В таком случае - не бейте палками.